# Deploying a contract that calls a contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

What is best practice on deploying a contract called within another contract with `web3.js`?

I have previously gone under the assumption that the contracts must be mined separately, and the caller must explcitly be told about the address of the callee?

Let's say we have this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Sub {
    bytes32 one;
    function set(bytes32 _one) {
        one = _one;
    }
    function get() constant returns(bytes32) {
        return one;
    }
}

contract Main {
    struct Data {   
        bytes32 one;
        Sub two;
    }
    Data public d;
    function set(bytes32 _main, bytes32 _sub) returns (uint) {
        Sub s = new Sub();
        s.set(_sub);
        d.one = _main;
        d.two = s;
    }
    function getBoth() constant returns (bytes32, bytes32) {
        return (d.one, d.two.get());
    }
}
```

Using [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) this yields two deploy code snippets where there is no explicit mention of the `sub` contract in the `main` deployment:

```
var browser_main_sol_mainContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"d","outputs":[{"name":"one","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"two","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getBoth","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_main","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_sub","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"set","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);
var browser_main_sol_main = browser_main_sol_mainContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

However, searching for the [sha3 digest](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#function-selector) `6d4ce63c` of the `get()` method in the **bytecode** of `main` matches twice. That suggests to me that it matches the *call* and the *method* itself, and thus the code of `sub` is embedded in the bytecode for `main`, and the need for an extra reference in the deployment seems unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend splitting the two contracts into two [separate files and then `import Sub.sol`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=import#importing-other-source-files) in the file `Main.sol`.

You could deploy either contract and hence Remix gives you two deploy code snippets. E.g. the `Sub` contract could be a standalone contract that is deployed at some point and then later on you deploy the `Main` contract and make it interact with your `Sub` contract. In your particular example there is no need to separately deploy the `Sub` contract as you instantiate it in the `Main` contract. You could, however also think about [inheriting](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#inheritance) `Main` from `Sub`, or you could deploy an instance of `Sub` separately, and store its address in `Main`. The latter might be useful if you have a lot of `Main` instances that could all use the same `Sub` contract, in this way the deploy bytecode of `Main` would get smaller (and hence cheaper to deploy).

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to deploy the contract to ? In memory VM, testnet or Mainnet?

For testnet or mainnet you can deploy using Truffle and to split your contracts into different files - then link them in your 2_deploy_contracts.js. This will auto-magically ensure that the referenced methods call each other:

Sub.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Sub {
 bytes32 one;
 function set(bytes32 _one) {
    one = _one;
 }

 function get() constant returns(bytes32) {
     return one;
 } 
}
```

Main.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11; 
import "./Sub.sol";"

contract Main {
    struct Data {   
        bytes32 one;
        Sub two;
    }
    Data public d;
    function set(bytes32 _main, bytes32 _sub) returns (uint) {
        Sub s = new Sub();
        s.set(_sub);
        d.one = _main;
        d.two = s;
    }
    function getBoth() constant returns (bytes32, bytes32) {
        return (d.one, d.two.get());
    }
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var Sub = artifacts.require("./Sub.sol");
var Main = artifacts.require("./Main.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Sub);
  deployer.link(Sub, Main);
  deployer.deploy(Main);
}
deployer.deploy(); 
};
```

More at:

http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations

I would also recommend using pragma solidity ^0.4.23; Lot's of nice changes in the newer version.

Hope this helps.